# Check colour of entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an if statement that checks the colour of column B.

It works if I target a single cell in column B not when I try ("B:B").

This is what I have.

```
Sub FOO()

    Dim answer As Range

    Set answer = Range("b:b")

    If answer.Interior.Color = vbRed Then

        MsgBox ("There is an issue with column B, please review.")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you cant say that, unless you are checking the whole column is red.  Look at FOR loops, both for next and for each.  This will help.

Comment: Thanks, only thing is I haven't learnt how to do loops yet, the excel guy in work left and I've been tasked with learning VB lol.

Comment: You'll use loops all the time, so look at them all do.while while..wend etc.

Comment: also, don't use B:B as it's too big, use a defined range, even if it is the entirety.  Range("b1:b100)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm a bit stuck on trying to get it to loop through my defined range though, you're right so far that if another cell in B column is a different color the message box doesn't appear.

Comment: please see my autofilter approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are getting many quality answers, here is the most optimized code. Fastest, I bet :)

It wont work if you are using one of the ancient versions of excel. anything 2007+ is fine.

```
Sub OptimizedFOO()

    Dim rngTemp

    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .Color = vbRed
    End With

    '/ Sheet1 is example sheet name
    Set rngTemp = Sheet1.Columns(2).Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox ("There is an issue with column B, please review.")
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Old answer

```
Sub FOO()

    Dim answer As Range
    Dim cell   As Range

    '/ This will show message if at least one cell is found with red color

    Set answer = Range("b:b")
    For Each cell In answer.Cells

        If answer.Interior.Color = vbRed Then

            MsgBox ("There is an issue with column B, please review.")
            Exit For

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working great now, you're a legend! I'm having to learn VB while at work here and today is my first day.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but give you my best guess.

If VB unifies the properties, then it unifies the properties of all the cells of the column. You can then compare the property to a value and this will be True if all rhe proeprties have that (same) value. Otherwise the comparison will be False.

So `If answer.Interior.Color = vbRed` will be True if all cells have this propety value `vbRed`. If you want to check if *any* of the cells have that color, you may need to iterate over all the cells.

I believe VB and the VB object model work like this, but again, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would find last used row on column B and than loop through them.

```
Sub FOO()

    Dim LR As Long, I As Long

    LR = findLastRow("Sheet1", "B")

    For I = 1 To LR
        If Range("B" & I).Interior.Color = vbRed Then

            MsgBox ("There is an issue with column B, please review.")
            Exit For

        End If
    Next I

End Sub

Function findLastRow(shtName As String, colLetter As String) As Long

    With Sheets(shtName)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            findLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range(colLetter & "1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            findLastRow = 1
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: wouldn't, `Worksheets(shtName).Range(colLetter & worksheets(shtName).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` suffice for findLastRow?

Comment: If Searching for value, why not search for the color itself. Killshot. :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I avoid finding last row that way. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1652222) answer for more details.

Comment: @cyboashu that's not a bad idea. I see that you have already "optimized" your answer. ;)

Comment: nps, that's why I use the last cell of the sheet, not range, then use up not down. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something using the autofilter, something like this

```
Function AnyRedCells(rngRangeToInspect As Excel.Range) As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rngRangeToInspect.AutoFilter
rngRangeToInspect.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
'   Using >1 as assuming header on column
AnyRedCells = (ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1)
rngRangeToInspect.AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Used like so

```
Sub OptimizedFOO2()
    If AnyRedCells(Range("b23:b26")) Then
          MsgBox ("There is an issue with column B, please review.")
    End If
End Sub
```